# Is it possible to separate docker image from folder with source files?

Tags: docker

Is it possible to separate docker image from folder where source files are located. And use image only to compile source files and then run if needed? I mean with out rebuilding an image only for compiling c++ source file. May be any tools exist for this?

Comment: just mount your folder in your container and execute what you need using the `docker exec` command

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're thinking of?  If you're used to working in a language like C++ where you do need to routinely build things, `docker build` a new image when the code changes is the same model; and if you're using a compiled language like this, there are a couple of ways to avoid having the source code in the final image.